# Print selected values from json

Tags: python, json

Input:

```
      {
    "ConcurrentAsyncGetReportInstances": {
    "Max": 200, 
     "Remaining": 200
     }, 
     "ConcurrentSyncReportRuns": {
      "Max": 20, 
      "Remaining": 20
      },
```

Required Output:

```
      {"Wraper":{
         "Max1":200,
         "Remaining1": 200,
         "Max2":20,
         "Remaining2": 20,
        },
```

Code used:

```
r=["Max"+str(i)  for i   in range(0)]
with open('hai.txt') as f:
     for line in f:
         if "Max" in line:
          print line
```

for the Above code output is :

```
  "Max": 200, 
  "Max": 20,
```

Please suggest any better code to give the output as mentioned tried all the possible ways which i known

Comment: Can you explain what exactly you're trying to do? Are you just trying to take the first JSON object and copy the values twice in it under the keys `Max2` and `Remaining2`?

Comment: no Actually i have Max and Remaining values like 30 so i wanted to print them with order like {Max1:value,Remaining1:value,Max2:value,Remaining2:value,.........Max30:value,Reamaining30:value,}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

data.json

```
  {
    "ConcurrentAsyncGetReportInstances": {
    "Max": 200, 
     "Remaining": 200
     }, 
     "ConcurrentSyncReportRuns": {
      "Max": 20, 
      "Remaining": 20
      }
  }
```

read_json.py

```
import json

with open('data.json') as data_file:    
    data = json.load(data_file)

output = {"Wraper": {}}
i = 1
for key, sub_data in data.iteritems():
    for key_sub, value in sub_data.iteritems():
        output["Wraper"] [key_sub + str(i)] = value
    i += 1

print output
```

output:

```
{'Wraper': {u'Max2': 20, u'Max1': 200, u'Remaining2': 20, u'Remaining1': 200}}
```

Comment: I am using Python2.7              **Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mapping.py", line 34, in <module>
    data = json.load(data_file)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 290, in load
    **kw)

Comment: me too, Python 2.7.6

Comment: Hi Andrea   I have problem with my Nested Json I am pasting link with all the details and existing code **[Link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1gF9R7o5BZZnlkmiEbo7_6oH8Gu0xcUGShCfG0gZiceQ/edit?usp=sharing)**  Please help me Thanks in advance and appreciated for your help

Comment: Hi Srihari, you are overwriting your values because your dict have repeated keys. A solution could be using a list instead of a dict to cumulate result. Pass to your flattenjson function a list (you called it odict) and then cumulate result with something like: odict.append({ky: 0}). At the end you got a list of dict but you have all your keys as you wish.

Comment: Thanks Andrea for the suggestion and for your time appreciated